# Issue while setting font size programmatically in ios7

Tags: ios7

I am working with `Xcode 5`. I am changing font size on button click by using code:

```
msgDetailTextView.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:60];
```

The code works for only `iOS 6` and not working on `iOS 7`.
How can I change the font size of my text view in `iOS 7` programmatically?

Comment: I guess msgDetailTextView is `nil`, check it.